# Using a print statement inside a python file and then running the file on google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I have a code written in Python language. In my google colab, I am calling a function 'func' which is inside a python file getmain.py stored in my drive. For debugging purposes, I want to use a print statement inside the function 'func' and I wish to see the result of the print statement in google colab output area (or any area, I just want to know the output). Using a simple print() inside 'func' doesn't do that, is there any way to do this on google colab? I cannot do this whole on my local machine, I need to use google colab only.
Thank you

Comment: And you already searched the internet? Because https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/courses/udacity_intro_to_tensorflow_for_deep_learning/l01c01_introduction_to_colab_and_python.ipynb sure seems to talk about this already.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans the link provided talks about print statements in google colab, but my question is how to use print statements in an external python file and see the results on colab. Let me know if I missed something? Thanks.

Comment: you'll have to be more detailed: colab code runs _on colab_ so how would it run a file that's on your computer rather than having been loaded into colab?